Is there a way to enable horizontal margin for a specific block element?
Sorry in advance for my dumb question.
I am slowly learning the new WordPress core theme functions for blocks.
I admit, I am fairly lost ‍♀️  .
The title says it all, I am trying to add the possibility to adjust left and right margins for a specific block in the editor (in my case, the group block).
Is there a way to do it ? I want to add margin left or right to some blocks, but I can't. It's so frustrating...
Where am I supposed to add this ? Is it even possible ? (I don't want to edit the css for a specific block, but I want to edit the spacing settings in the editor so I can add margin left or right.)
Thanks so much for your kind help !

